regex_replace function
I'm trying to replace the following string with offset of 2 characters from beginning and end.
Example input: A9999999999
Expected output: A9********99
I have tried the following but not able to narrow down to exact format

regexp_replace(a, '[0-9]', '*') as  a
REGEXP_REPLACE(a, '[0-9]', '*', 6) as a
REGEXP_REPLACE(a, '\1((.*)\4$)', '\1*******\3') as  a


Would be helpful to mention if it's about fixed or variable length.

REGEXP_REPLACE('A9999999999', '(.{2}).*(.{2})', '\1*******\2')
based on you examples, it looks like your string will always be the same length.
I select the first and last characters in capture groups and use those in the final string

This appears to replace one character with an asterisk. As I understand the question, it wants all characters except the first two and the last two to be replaced.

I tried this : select   REGEXP_REPLACE('A9999999999', '(?<=..).(?=..)', '*') from dual
this is the output i got : A9999999999

@AdrianHHH , thats right

@AdrianHHH it should have multiple selections, and each one gets replaced by the asterisk. Not sure why it's not working for you, it is for me. I'll see if I can figure out what the issue is

Looks like capture groups aren't supported in plsql, so I've adjusted my answer

@SamB just perfect, thank you   " output : A9*******99

You still have capture groups. I think you meen lookarounds.

@Barmar yes I did thanks

You don't need regular expressions. Find the first two characters, last two characters and generate a sequence of * of the correct length in the middle:
SELECT SUBSTR(a, 1, 2)
       || LPAD('*', LENGTH(a) - 4, '*')
       || SUBSTR(a, -2) AS a
FROM   table_name

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (a) AS
SELECT 'A9999999999' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



A




A9*******99



fiddle
